# SQL to Bigquery

Tags: mysql, sql, database, google-bigquery, google-cloud-sql

How do I convert following sql to bigquery

```
SELECT table1.field1, table2.field2, table2.field3, table2.field4, table2.field5, table2.field6, table2.field7 
FROM table1
JOIN EACH table2 on table1.cookie=table2.cookie 
GROUP BY table2.field3,table1.field1,table2.field2,table2.field4,table2.field5,table2.field6,table2.field7
WHERE table2.field3=1176;
```

I am getting following error **" Encountered " "WHERE" "WHERE "" at line 2, column 1 "**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `WHERE` is in the wrong place. `WHERE` should be before `GROUP BY` and after the last `JOIN` or after `FROM` if there are no `JOINS`.

Try this:

```
SELECT table1.field1, table2.field2, table2.field3, table2.field4, table2.field5, table2.field6, table2.field7 
FROM table1 
JOIN EACH table2 on table1.cookie=table2.cookie 
WHERE table2.field3=1176;
GROUP BY table2.field3,table1.field1,table2.field2,table2.field4,table2.field5,table2.field6,table2.field7
```

Comment: `EACH` is an optional hint that both the left and right tables might be large (i.e. > 8MB) tables. See [Google BigQuery Query Reference](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#joins). Share and enjoy.